# Don't use image flairs on the profile accounts page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, flair, related-accounts

The profile accounts page always annoys me a lot because of the huge amount of time it takes to load. The problem with the page using image flairs for each account is that for devs and active users (who have accounts on a large number of sites) the page takes forever to load, sometimes with one or two of the flairs not loading successfully because of some of them will always timeout.

In addition to that, the page is not accessible, because of the lack of `alt` attributes, so if any one of the image fails to load I'll have to reload the page to see the entire list. The web developer in me is also annoyed at the waste of bandwidth loading the huge number of images when the same information can be presented with HTML for a lot less bytes and no waiting time.

The flairs also repeats the display name of the user for each site. Although it is possible that the user may have different names on different sites, it is exceedingly rare and probably not worth displaying at all. The list is difficult to scan through because a lot of the times the only difference would be that tiny favicon on the left side of the name, and perhaps the font color.

---

I hope I have provided a compelling case to change the account page to something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This seems to be pretty much done...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84380/has-area51-rep-been-removed-from-related-accounts/84614#84614)