# Has Area51 rep been removed from Related Accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, related-accounts

It was there until recently, I think.

There are also a couple of questions about this from six months ago, asking why it's not on there, so I guess it got added around that time ... then a couple of days ago got removed again.

If it's gone, any reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accounts tab is getting some love too, as part of the ongoing refinements to the user page.

Step 1 was a lot of background work (making associations faster*), we're now into Step 2 which is the UI.

Area 51 associations still work (you'll get the +100 bonus and all), and will be back to being displayed <del>within the next day or two</del> *very shortly across the entire network*.

### Before

[image: old accounts tab]

### After

[image: new accounts tab]

<sub>*Most people probably wouldn't notice, but once you got to 10 Stack Exchange accounts or so each new one was costing you about 20 seconds of your life *just to establish associations*.</sub>

Comment: I am seeing the question **"Eeeek! What happened to my Flairs?"**

Comment: @YOU - flair is still around, it just wasn't meant to be displayed in massive 4x10 arrays.

Comment: The new Accounts page is great!

Comment: I likes it! One thing though, the explanatory sub-titles make it hard to get an overview. Maybe hide those from 1k+ users on the assumption that they are aware of what each site is for?

Comment: @Pekka - We've got 48 sites (excluding child metas) in the network, its kind of hard to believe that a rep threshold could accurately capture a user's awareness of all of them (especially since we keep launching new ones).